# Front end Submit not posting to Custom Post type

Tags: custom-post-types, front-end

I have a custom script that allows to add per form submit to add contacts to a custom post type. But for some reason it always adds the data to the posts instead into the post type.

i have tried everything so far but no luck here is the code for the form i took out the form verification out since that part is working

```
        if( !isset( $hasError ) ) {

        $submit_to_contact_manager = array(
            'post_title' => 'Request from '. esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['request_lastname'])),
            'post-type' => 'tpf_cnm',
            'post_status' => 'pending'
        );

        $contactmanager_id = wp_insert_post($submit_to_contact_manager);

        if($contactmanager_id)
        {

            // Update Custom Meta
            update_post_meta($contactmanager_id, 'tpf_first_name_preorders', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['request_firstname'])));
            update_post_meta($contactmanager_id, 'tpf_last_name_preorders', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['request_lastname'])));
            update_post_meta($contactmanager_id, 'tpf_email_preorders', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['request_email'])));
            update_post_meta($contactmanager_id, 'tpf_preorder_desc', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['request_message'])));
            update_post_meta($contactmanager_id, 'tpf_preorder_desc', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['request_category'])));


        }
    }
```

and here is the post type function

```
        add_action('init', 'tpf_cnm_init');

    function tpf_cnm_init(){

    $tpf_cnm_type_labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Contacts', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Contact', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New Contact', 'image'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Contact'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Contact'),
    'new_item' => __('Add Contact'),
    'all_items' => __('View Contacts'),
    'view_item' => __('View Contact'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Contacts'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No Contacts found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Contacts found in Trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Contacts'
    );

    $tpf_cnm_type_args = array(
        'labels' => $tpf_cnm_type_labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => _x( 'contact-manager', 'URL slug', 'your_text_domain' ) ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'comments', 'custom-fields' )
      ); 

    register_post_type('tpf_cnm', $tpf_cnm_type_args); 
    }
```

any help would be nice im going crazy with this atm thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to correct:

`'post-type' => 'tpf_cnm',`

and make it:

`'post_type' => 'tpf_cnm',`

Comment: Oh my god your right damn i feel like a fool haha thank you for pointing that out i guess i looked at all the wrong spots